# Multiple files not uploading, not moving file in php

Tags: php, arrays, file-upload

Im trying to upload multiple files but my code is bypassing the "move_uploaded_file" code. What is missing?

```
foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $file) {
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . $file;
        if (move_uploaded_file($file, $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ".$_FILES["file"]["name"]. " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`move_uploaded_file` needs to get the temporary file name: `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`

```
foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
    $target_dir = "./";
    $target_file = $target_dir . $file['name'];
    if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file " . $file["name"] . " has been uploaded.<br />";
    } else {
        echo "Error uploading the file " . $file["name"] . ".<br />";
    }
}
```

Small HTML snippet for the upload form:

```
<form action="./testpage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file1" type="file" /><br />
    <input name="file2" type="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload!" />
</form>
```

Comment: Well now im getting this error: Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in xxxxxx . Do you know what is that?

Comment: Just tested my code again, working fine. Please show me your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);$i++)
    {
     if(!is_uploaded_($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]))
     {
    $messages[] = 'No  uploaded';
    }
    else
     {
     if(@copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],$target.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]))
     {
      $messages[] = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i].' uploaded';
     }
     else
    $messages[] = 'Uploading '.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i].' Failed';
     }
     }
     }
```

html:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" method="post">
<input id="uploadFile" name="file[]" type="file" />
<input id="uploadFile" name="file[]" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="uploadt"  />
</form>
```